# Rails Devise Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

Can someone give me an example of how to do something like this.
I have a user setup with devise, according to the way in this tutorial
https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise/wiki/Tutorial-%28Walkthrough%29 (I skipped the stuff related to subdomain)
now say if I wanted to have a user make many tweets, so a user and a user alone can upload tweets, but anyone can see them, how would that be accomplished.
I find rails really tough, so if you could explain thoroughly that would be good (i.e. go to routes.rb insert get 'users/ ...)

Answer (score 0):

Devise is simply an authentication gem. If you want to post tweets to Twitter, you're going to have to get into omniauth with devise. Theres a railscast for that: http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

And devise has a wiki on direct integration: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

If you're talking more hypothetically about creating and showing posts then after you  have devise set up, just make filters on what users can do like this

```
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]
```

That would go in the Posts controller right under the class declaration. Basically it says before you load pages new, create, edit, or destroy make sure the user is authenticated by calling authenticate (I believe devise already has that `authenticate` method built in but if not it is easy to write). Then any person could go to the show method to see the tweets, but could not create them for that user.

Comment: So if I wanted to link the user to make a post, say in _registration_items.html.erb, I would put link_to(???) or, ... how would I do that

Comment: I know that probably sounds simple, but rails is really bugging me, im not sure if i need to declare specific routes for this or what?

Comment: There would be a model/controller/view for posts. You would link to posts/new to show the form to create one, and sure you could use link_to. There are fundamental concepts your missing here though, you really need to start from the beginning or you'll end up rewriting tons of code, try this: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1934356549/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=486539851&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B001EMQRDM&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=0GFQMW3D87Q1X9JZJ9M3.